# simple SAML php Drupal Initial Load causes partial loading of $user variable

Tags: 7, users, hooks

I have a very weird issue where the $user variable doesnt load fully during an initial login into the site. I am using simpleSAMLphp login module which routes me outside of the drupal site to authenticate and then brings be back to the drupal site. Upon coming back to the Drupal site, some functions are not loaded due to the fact that my "user role" isn't fully populated. This causes issues with context and other role based conditions. I tried moving the simpleSAMLphp module's weight lower to load it before other modules load, but that didn't seem to work.

Below are 2 screenshots of the initial login and the second image is after a page refresh which populates the $user variable properly. Again, this only causes issues on initial load of the site, but after a refresh everything functions normally again.

As you can see here, this is the first initial load. Notice the **roles** array only shows the role id only ([5] > 5) :

[image]

---

**Now this is what we see on the refresh. It shows alot less data, and the roles show the full role name**

[image]

---

Now the question is why is it doing this? It seems that its in an in between limbo before my $user gets updated with the **authenticated role** as the role names aren't even processed yet as it's only showing the role id during the initial load.

Is there a flowchart of how the $user variable gets populated and constructed on a drupal inital load?

Comment: A work around to this weird issue was to have the user redirect back to the homepage via rules upon login. After the redirect the site functions normally again, but the problem still persists without this hack.